# Typescript TypeError: ......toDateString is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am new to typescript and this might be something very trivial. Please help.

I am trying to extract minutes and seconds from typescript Date variable.
I have a variable timestamp declared as Date. But when I try to use functions on it like toDateString() or getMinutes() or getTime(), I get the above error saying TypeError: timestamp.getMinutes() is not a function.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a compile time error ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's likely that your timestamp is not a date, just a number that represents the [number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_timestamp).

All you need to do is convert your timestamp to a Date, like this:

```
let currentDate = new Date(timestamp);
```

Then you can call any `Date` functions you want on it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It works in one place. But I don't understand the same code gives the above error in a different file.

Comment: I used :
const time = new Date(tempData.timestamp);
result.push({x: time.getTime(), y: tempData.heatSinkTemperature});

It gives error in this place. Is there anything wrong here?. Thank you.

Comment: Well, `time.getTime()` will return the original timestamp. Do you want to do `x: time` instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Angular DatePipe to achieve this-

```
{{current_date | date: 'shortTime'}}
```

You can find more information here -
https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Answer (score 0):

###### toDateString() is not a function is showing because u may used it with any variable

toDateString() is a method which can be used with a date object only

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31850850)